# Editing modification times of files on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, date-modified

How can I set the modification time of a file on Mac OS X from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MacOS, and most (all?) Unix-like OSs have a [touch](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html) command, that lets you modify access + mtimes.

on MacOS:

```
touch 06011200 file
```

Will set the mtime of 'file' to June 1st of this year.

GNU's version lets you specify times in a slightly more convenient format:

```
touch -d yesterday file
```